# Return HTML input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like to have my code return the HTML input using an alert.

I tried to with this code, below, but the output was nothing. I am pretty sure that its not the button...

```html
<center>
  <h3>Enter The Username And Password To Unlock This Computer</h3>
  <script>
    function incorrect() {
      var user = document.getElementById("username");
      var pass = document.getElementById("password");
      text = "the username '" + user + "' is incorrect, and the password '" + pass + "' is also incorrect"
      console.log(text)
      alert(text)
    }
  </script>
  <form>
    <h6>Username</h6><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
    <h6>Password</h6><input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="">
    <br><button type="button" onclick="incorrect">Unlock</button>


  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: Try to change `onclick="incorrect"` to `onclick="incorrect()"`

Comment: An alert can't have inputs, it's just text. You can either make a custom alert that does what you want or you can use the standard alert to display messages.

Comment: `<center>` tag is deprecated for more than 10 years, it's use is not advisable and it can stop working at any time

Comment: Well, @CalvinNunes, it still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the text that is being typed in or just the html input block?

```html
<center>
  <h3>Enter The Username And Password To Unlock This Computer</h3>
  <script>
    function incorrect() {
      var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
      text = "the username '" + user + "' is incorrect, and the password '" + pass + "' is also incorrect"
      console.log(text)
      alert(text)
    }
  </script>
  <form>
    <h6>Username</h6><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
    <h6>Password</h6><input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="">
    <br><button type="button" onclick="incorrect()">Unlock</button>


  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: The text that is being typed in please, @DCR, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is about braces, you should use `<br><button type="button" onclick="incorrect()">Unlock</button>`

```js
      function incorrect(){
         var user = document.getElementById("username");
        var pass = document.getElementById("password");
        text = "the username '"+user+"' is incorrect, and the password '"+pass+"' is also incorrect"
        console.log(text)
        alert(text)
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <center>
    <h3>Enter The Username And Password To Unlock This Computer</h3>

    <form>
      <h6>Username</h6><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
      <h6>Password</h6><input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="">
      <br><button type="button" onclick="incorrect()">Unlock</button>


    </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are also trying to concatenate `[object HTMLInputElement]` instead of using `.value` to extract the value.

Comment: I just tried it and it gave me `“the username '[object HTMLInputElement]' is incorrect, and the password '[object HTMLInputElement]' is also incorrect”`

Comment: @ThePythonCoder right, this is what you've coded in js function

Comment: @Zera question was why function is not called, not how to implement proper validation or fix error message

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="button">sad</button>


let t = document.querySelector('.button');

t.addEventListener('click', function () {
                let y = document.querySelector('.input').value;
                console.log(y);
           });
```

Comment: Please ellaborate a little bit more your answer and tell OP how it works.

Comment: its easy.  we take value from input  let y = document.querySelector('.input').value; and do with this data what we want   console.log(y);

Comment: @ВадимШляхов Please edit that explanation into your answer.